# Image slide show

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to create my own image slide show. For this, I want to user to point to a directory, and get all images from this directory. Then I want to start the slide show. How can I achieve that the best?

I want to do it this way, so I can display my own live twitter feed over it. If you know an app that does this already, I don't need to build this app...

Comment: The title of your question is a bit cryptic. What are you trying to do exactly? what do you mean by "native file browser"?

Comment: I asked my question again, in a way that is (I think) more clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a scripting bridge to iPhoto? Then you could pretty easily do a slideshow with CoreAnimation.

Comment: I just started coding in Objective-C / Cocoa... I used to do PHP only... Can you maybe give a reference URL?

Comment: Hmm... Bill Dudney's screencast on PragProg will actually show you how to do exactly this... grab photos from your library and do a sort of coverflow type thing. http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdcora/creating-a-compelling-user-interface-with-core-animation

Answer (score 0):

You want `IKSlideshow` in the ImageKit framework.